# Query on for loop in List of Lists in Python

Tags: python

Why is the first code not giving the desired result of 5,6,1 if I am using range (0,le). I had to use (-1,le) to get all the values of the last column. If I use normal lists the for loop works fine.

```
def result( game ):
    print game
    le = len(game)-1
    print le
    for i in range(0,le):
        m = game[i][le]
        print m

winner = [[2, 2, 5],[2, 1, 6],[2, 1, 1]]
result(winner)
```

Outputs:

```
[[2, 2, 5], [2, 1, 6], [2, 1, 1]]
2
5
6
```

Second version:

```
def result( game ):
    print game
    le = len(game)-1
    print le
    for i in range(-1,le):
        m = game[i][le]
        print m

winner = [[2, 2, 5],[2, 1, 6],[2, 1, 1]]
result(winner)
```

Outputs:

```
[[2, 2, 5], [2, 1, 6], [2, 1, 1]]
2
1
5
6
```

Thanks all for your answers.

One other question regarding the same code --

Can you clarify another thing for me? Say if I use the below in the above code -->

```
le = len(game)
print le
for i in range(0,le):
```

Why am I getting the following error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                              
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>                                                                                                                                          
    result(winner)                                                                                                                                                              
  File "main.py", line 6, in result                                                                                                                                             
    m = game[i][le]                                                                                                                                                             
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You should put your output here vs. screenshots linked to another site.

Comment: `range(start, stop)` does not include the `stop` value. So your `le` is off by one. `range(0, le+1)` would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AChampion both for your answer and guidance regarding the formatting of the question.

Comment: @AChampion - I have one other query and posted the same in the above Query. Can you take a look?

Comment: A lists index starts at `0` and goes to `len(list)-1`. `list[len(list)]` is always out of range. The last item in a list can always be referenced with `list[-1]`. Using the original `le = len(game)-1` and `range(0, le+1)` should work - did you try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is right, the reason is  `le = len(game)-1` and when you use `range(0,le)` in the for loop you actually never reach the last index!

Take a simple example:

```
a=[[2, 2, 5], [2, 1, 6], [2, 1, 1]]
```

Now print,

`a[0][2]` ==> 5

`a[-1][2]` ==> 1

So in your second case you get the 1 because you are counting the array from the end rather than the start!

In your case use:

```
def result( game ):
    print game
    le = len(game)-1
    print le
    for i in range(0,len(game)):
        m = game[i][le]
        print m

winner = [[2, 2, 5],[2, 1, 6],[2, 1, 1]]
result(winner)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Itay has pointed out, `range` doesn't include the last value. You just need to change your loop to:

```
for i in range(0,le+1):
```

for it to loop through all nested lists *in the correct order*.

By the way: Your second solution is also not giving you your desired solution if you look closely. If you start your range at `-1` you are printing the value `game[-1][le]` which is the same as `game[2][le]`. So you're essentially starting with the last row and then going to the first and second row in your second solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the second parameter of `range` :

```
for i in range(inclusive, exclusive):
    do ...
```